# Android fragment popBackStack and replace not removing view

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to learn to use fragments.

Suppose i have one activity, with 2 fragments - `FragmentA` and `FragmentB`.

In my activity i add the fragment, with what i thought was the ability to remove a fragment view when i press the back button:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        mFragmentA = new FragmentA();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, mFragmentA).addToBackStack("fragA").commit();
    }
```

and in my FragmentA's view, i have 2 buttons. one supposedly for going back, and one for replacing FragmentA with FragmentB.

So here's what FragmentA looks like:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a_layout, null);

        Button backButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.frag_a_back);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack("fragA", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            }
        });

        Button nextButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.frag_a_next);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                FragmentB fragB = new FragmentB();

                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragB).commit();
            }
        });

        container.addView(view);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Question:
When i go to fragmentB or if i press the back button, why does FragmentA's two buttons still show up on the screen?  I want the back button to remove FragmentA. Is the fragment getting removed/detached but the view is not?

(i'm using FrameLayout for everything and i can see FragmentA view still there)

*EDIT* =============================

okay i realized there is a `onDestroyView()` method, but i'm not sure if it's the right way to remove my FragmentA's views?

it would require me to hold on to an instance of the parent view, and a reference var to my fragment layout view; and that way i can use the parent view to remove all views here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to do `container.addView(view);` explicitly. Just return the inflated View. The following changes might help.

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a_layout, null);

        Button backButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.frag_a_back);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack("fragA", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            }
        });

        Button nextButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.frag_a_next);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                FragmentB fragB = new FragmentB();

                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragB).commit();
            }
        });

        //container.addView(view);

        return view;
    }
```